# What do you call a coined term like "Cobra effect"?

Tags: word-request, dictionaries

Looked on wiktionary:

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cobra_effect

and it just says it's a noun. How do you look for coined words on Wiktionary. I want to search for coined words instead of ordinary word like abdomen, which might have been coined by someone, but can be found on a dictionary. Is there a word for composite words? I can only use the category noun to search for coined composite words, but that means I will end up with regular words like abdomen in the search result and it's a problem. I want to be able to search for composite coined terms like Cobra Effect.

Comment: "it just says it's a noun". Logically, if it doesn't mark these words as composite coined terms, then the answer would be you can't search for them specifically.
How about a google search for coined words ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you mean [neologism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neologism). [Charles Lutwidge Dodgson](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Lewis-Carroll) was (in)famous for coining such words as `chortle`, `galumphing` and `uffish`.

Many neologisms are [portmanteau words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau), another term Dodgson used: a *portmanteau* is a suitcase that opens into two sections. To quote Dodgson, it's "two meanings packed into one word like a portmanteau".